# Conditionally apply generic class name using ngClass in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular6

I have a button arrays as shown below

```
this.btns = [
 {btnClass: 'primary', btnText: 'Verified', id: 'verfied'},
 {btnClass: 'danger', btnText: 'Rejected', id: 'rejected'}
]
```

My html template has this piece of code

```
<div  *ngFor="let btn  of btns">
   <button class="lui-button lui-small" 
   [ngClass]="{ btn.btnClass : btn.id === status}">{{btn.btnText}}
   </button>
</div>
```

The value of *status* can be either verified,rejected, or default

The html is throwing me a parse error as

```
[ngClass]="{ btn.btnClass : btn.id === status}"
```

is not valid, i tried doing [ngClass]="{ [btn.btnClass] : btn.id === status}" , but in vain.

I understand the reason for parse error, but Is there anyway I can change something and get className as generic here ?

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That expression is invalid, even in JavaScript...

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, need a way to change something and  make it work if possible

Comment: What does the `id` or `status` have to do with the applied class? Can't you just apply `btnClass` like this: `[ngClass]="{ option.btnClass }"`?

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst btnClass should only get applied if the value of status and id matches.Status value can be either verfied or rejected or default.So incase of default, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let btn  of btns">
    <ng-template let-class="btn.btnClass" [ngIf]="true">
        <button 
      class="lui-button lui-small"
      [ngClass]="{ class : btn.id === status}">
      {{btn.btnText}}
   </button>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your class as:

```
[ngClass]="btn.id === status ? btn.btnClass : ''"
```